# Parse String with a Tag like Format

Tags: java, android, regex

What I need to parse:

```
[at:1761764]@my_nick_name[/at] my random comment.
```

What I would like to get:

```
@my_nick_name my random comment.
```

I need to do it in an android application. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: you can get the first index of [ and ] and extract a substring.. and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final String a = "[at:1761764]@my_nick_name[/at] my random comment.";
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", ""));
```

This will replace anything between `[]` (including them) by an empty string, which is equivalent to removing it from the string.

Explanation for the regex:

`\\[` -> [ character (you need to escape it since it's a special character in regexes)

`.*?` -> 0 or more of any character, not greedy

`\\]` -> ] character

Answer (score 0):

With this regex:

```
(^\[\w*:\d*\])|(\[/\w*\])
```

You select the:

[at:1761764] and [/at]

Later you can remove this ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simple version:

```
 String[] parts = input.split("]");
 String firstPart = parts[1];
 firstPart = firstPart.substring(0, firstPart.indexOf("["));
 String secondPart = parts[2];
```

Regular Expressions are another good option in general KISS.

Comment: IMHO a regex is more KISS than this. But I guess this depends on how comfortable you are with regexes :)

Comment: I think it depends on if capturing of the two groups is needed. Your solution is excellent if it is not.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see any such capturing requirement in the question.

Comment: Yup, that's why your answer is better given the way it is asked. Cheers.